# How to have different API url in next.js app depending on currently used subdomain

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js

So i'm building a next.js app and currently i'm having my API url for requests set up as env variable, and i'm using it like:

```
<Link href={`${process.env.DB_HOST}/download/${props.id}`}>
    <button type="button">Lataa</button>
</Link>
```

So what i want to do is have that host name to be "dynamic" depending which subdomain i'm using, like http://localhost:4000/download/1 or http://something.localhost:4000/download/.

Any ideas what could be best approach to do that? This might be a tricky one because solution must work in both, client and server component.